# Initializing multiple View Models for each Lazy Column in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

For an object detection android app I want to overlay data that comes from a server for several images. In different attempts I got either the issue, that the overlay disappears on rotation of the device or that all images use the same view model since they use the same instance of the view model.

I  use the following ViewModel.

```
class AnalysisViewModel(...): ViewModel()
{
private val analysisResponseLiveData: MutableLiveData<AnalysisResponse> = MutableLiveData()
...
// Expose LiveData for observing AnalysisResponse
fun updateAnalysisResponse(response: AnalysisResponse) {
analysisResponseLiveData.value = response
}
fun getAnalysisResponseLiveData(): MutableLiveData<analysisResponse> = analysisResponseLiveData

    // Method to fetch AnalysisResponse from API
    fun fetchAnalysisResponse(file: File) {
        // Perform API call and retrieve AnalysisResponse object

...
```

A collection of View Models should be created in the Main Activity as  `remember {mutableStateListOf<AnalysisViewModel>()}`. I create and add an AnalysisViewModel in two ways. One is using 'by ViewModel()'. This works for the first item, but when adding a second image both images share the same overlay. When I use `remember {AnalysisViewModel()}` then the overlay is gone on rotation.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
        setContent {
            Theme {

// Collection of View Models
val analysisViewModels =  remember {mutableStateListOf<AnalysisViewModel>()}

        val analysisViewModel: analysisViewModel by viewModels()

// I can add a new View Model this way, but then it disappears on rotation
val analysisViewModel2 = remember {AnalysisViewModel()}

// If I try to use by viewModels for a second View Model and fetch the API response for the second image, the overlay of the first Image overwritten.
//      val analysisViewModel2: analysisViewModel by viewModels()

        analysisViewModels.add(analysisViewModel)
    
        analysisViewModels.add(analysisViewModel2)
    
    
        Surface(
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
           color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
    
             LazyColumn()
                    {

items(
items = analysisViewModels,
key = {analysisViewModel -> analysisViewModel.uuid.toString()}
) { analysisViewModel ->

     Surface(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium, elevation = 1.dp) {

//   val analysisViewModel: AnalysisViewModel by viewModels()
// ERROR: On rotation a new instance of a view model is initialized which overwrites

     ImageScreen(
        analysisViewModel,
        uids[0],
        onResponseReceived = { response ->
        // Update the analysisResponseState with the new response
                                       
     analysisViewModel.updateAnalysisResponse(response)
                              }
        )
}
```

I was thinking of using just one view model and have a list of overlay data in there. But then I would have to pass the data of all view models to a view that should only be concerned with one item.

Hope someone can help me out.

Best,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of stuff to be fixed before you can have a result:

1. One ViewModel per Activity. You are right - it is better to have one VM.
2. VM should not be created by you because then you won't get auto-restore after rotation. More  - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel
3. It is better to store a collection of models inside ViewModel and show LazyColumn based on that.